# Android Tab Layout not taking up full width with custom view

Tags: android, android-tablayout, androiddesignsupport

[Android TabLayout tabPaddingTop and tabPaddingBottom not being removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34915914/android-tablayout-tabpaddingtop-and-tabpaddingbottom-not-being-removed)

Please refer to the above issue as well.

Even since i updated my design library to "23.2.0", Tab layout is all messed up.

The below image is my Tab Layout.

Xml Part :-

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="@dimen/dp2"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance" />
```

styles xml :-

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_156084</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/sp14</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

I have set padding to -1dp and even did tabGravity to fill but nothing is working.

This code used to work in earlier versions but now if i am downgrading it, i am getting a no class def found error on TintManager.

[image]

Comment: can you post whole xml file

Comment: The tab is having the padding internally,. other parts of xml does not have any effect on it

Comment: @RahulGupta How did you solve this issue ? I am facing same issue. Tab is taking extra space and fitting full screen.

Answer (score 8):

Setting different values or layout params did not work, so the only solution I got was to add the following, after you add the tabs to your tab layout,

```
final ViewGroup test = (ViewGroup)(tabs.getChildAt(0));//tabs is your Tablayout
int tabLen = test.getChildCount();

for (int i = 0; i < tabLen; i++) {
            View v = test.getChildAt(i);
            v.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Try adding below attributes to TabLayout:

```
app:tabPaddingStart="-1dp"
app:tabPaddingEnd="-1dp"
```

Hope it'll work.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of dealing with `TabLayout` subviews, you can access `TabLayout.Tab` view directly and set the padding to `0` just like the code below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
    View tabView = tabLayout.getTabAt(i).view;
    tabView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

I'm doing this in the `onCreateView` callback and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass your tabLayout to this method and it's done!

```
private void setTabLayoutMatchParent(TabLayout tabLayout) {
    final ViewGroup tabLayoutChild = (ViewGroup)(tabLayout.getChildAt(0));
    int tabLen = tabLayoutChild.getChildCount();

    for (int j = 0; j < tabLen; j++) {
        View v = tabLayoutChild.getChildAt(j);
        v.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked really well for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck for hours until I found the method `tab.setCustomView(idRes)`. Changing from inflated to this worked for me. Alernatively, if you are inflating you can use `TabLayout.TabView` as root viewgroup.

Apart from this, I am not sure if it is helpful but I used `minWidth` to the custom view layout.

This is what I [wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5bMt.png)

Comment: By doing setCustomView(idRes), layout parameters are correctly interpreted cause the inflated view is directly linked to a rootView. This saves me a lot of time. Thank yu !

Answer (score 1):

There are attributes in TabLayout : **app:tabPaddingStar**t and **app:tabPaddingEnd**

You can set -1 to both of them in order to remove padding start and end in custom view of TabLayout.

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tlEmojis"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabPaddingStart="-1dp"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="-1dp"
        app:tabMaxWidth="@dimen/dimen_48dp"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding TabLayout in LinearLayout like:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In Styles.xml add:

```
 <style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: are you using a viewpager also?

Comment: yes i am, but view pager does not have any effect on this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was giving **fixed height** to the custom layout that i use for tabs. 
Using `match_parent` fixed my issue.